# Подскажите пожалуйста приложение-клиент L2TP/IPSec на Android 12

Tags: android, vpn, app, l2tp

Из 12-го андроида вырезали L2TP/IPSec ((

Безуспешно потратил день в попытках подружить android 12 и MikroTik по IKEv2. OpenVPN подключается, но внешний адрес клиент всё так же свой показывает, а не сервера. Устал долбиться с маршрутизацией и настройкой сервера. L2TP сервер настроен и нормально работал без танцев с бубном.

Установил strongswan - так там тоже одни IKEv2.
**Есть ли приложение-клиент L2TP/IPSec на андроид?**